# is there a specification for RESTful APIs

Tags: rest, specifications

I have seen many ways/guides/tutrials implementing RESTful web services, I have even implemented many myself. I understand the basic principles that a restful service should follow because I have inferred them from many different sources, articles, other web services,  etc.

Now I am studying the protocols and standards that govern the web in more detail , reading specs, RFCs, etc

Is there a document, RFC or specification that is widely accepted that explains what a RESTful web service should be compliant with?.

Comment: I voted to close this as this sounds like a request to collect a list of external resources on this topic, which is not in scope with the agenda of SO. In addition to that, the [dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm) on REST is probably the common truth on this matter, if you are really interested in how REST fits in into the big picture. Also Fielding has clarified what a service following a REST architecture [should and should not do](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)

Comment: This is a very valid question and should stay open.

Comment: This should not have been closed imo. @RomanVottner comment is actually a pretty decent answer. The only reason to consider this question as a request for gathering documents is if _you already knew the answer was "no there is not a spec per se"_. Once you know that, then it follows that the best you can do is collect documents.

Answer (score 18):

In 2008, Leonard Richardson [introduced a maturity model](https://www.crummy.com/writing/speaking/2008-QCon/act3.html) for web services, based on the three primary technologies in the web stack:

- URI
- HTTP
- Hypermedia

## URI

URI's are defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

## HTTP

HTTP in 2022 is defined by

- [RFC 9110](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110) -- HTTP Semantics
- [RFC 9111](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9111) -- HTTP Caching
- [RFC 9112](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9112) -- HTTP/1.1
- [RFC 9113](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9113) -- HTTP/2
- [RFC 9114](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9114) -- HTTP/3

HTTP in 2018 was defined by

- [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) -- Message Syntax and Routing
- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) -- Semantics and Content
- [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232) -- Conditional Requests
- [RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233) -- Range Requests
- [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) -- Caching
- [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235) -- Authentication

## Hypermedia

This is the hard one.  The ubiquitous hypermedia media type is still HTML, you could start with [HTML 5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/).

A number of API try to use [JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259), but JSON doesn't define *links*; so if you want to go that route, you need to find a JSON variant which defines links.

[Kevin Sookocheff wrote](https://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/) a nice overview of some options

- [JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/)
- [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html)
- [Collection+JSON](http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/)
- [SIREN](https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren)

Comment: While appreciate the response (I really do), I'm asking specifically about RESTful APIs. I have already read the HTTP 1.1 RFCs fully, but RESTful APIs seem to be a **very specific** way of using HTTP, URLs and Hypermedia.